# How to fix lags and "Exception caught in AudioQueueInternalNotifyRunning - error -66671" when playing sound on iPadOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I tried to fix this issue with a non-local variable, but I still have the same error and the interface (SwiftUI) is lagging. Here is my SoundManager file:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class SoundService {
    static let shared = SoundService()
    private var soundEffect: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    public func tockSound() {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tock.mp3", ofType:nil)!
        playSound(path: path)
    }
    
    // other sounds...
    
    private func playSound(path: String) {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            soundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            print("[SoundService] Play sound")
            soundEffect?.play()
        } catch {
            print("[SoundService] Could not load file \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I use in the interface to play the sound:

```
SoundService.shared.tockSound()
```

Comment: I have exact this issue on iPhone 14 Pro Max simulator, but it works on the iPad simulator. Have you figured out the solution yet?

Comment: Yes @zs2020, I fixed it with a workaround. I will add a solution to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix this issue with a local variable that inserts a timer - so there is a very short gap between new sounds. `Time_Control` is a module for pausing code I found here on StackOverflow.

```
private var control: Time_Control = Time_Control(0)

private func playSound(path: String) {
    
    // Plays sound only if sounds are activated in app settings
    if serviceActivated {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            
            // start an async timer so the maximum is 10 sound effects per second (= 0.1 seconds)
            if control.can_send {
                control = Time_Control(0.1)
                control.start()
                soundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                print("[SoundService] Play sound")
                //            soundEffect?.currentTime = 0
                soundEffect?.play()
            }
            
        } catch {
            print("[SoundService] Could not load file \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```